# How do I use jQuery Validation and Regex to check each row of a text area for a pattern?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to do some form validation using jQuery Validation.  In the form I have a textarea for Serial Numbers and in that textarea users will paste a specifically formatted serial number, one per line (like copying from Excel).  I want to loop through each line in the textarea and validate that each serial number is properly formatted.  If not, throw an error.  If all Serial Numbers check out, then allow the form to submit.  Each serial number is in the format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX where the X can be any digit or upper case letter.

I've got this working such that the entire form validation works the way I want it to, with the exception that it currently only checks one line of the Serial Number textarea, rather than looping through each to find an improperly formatted Serial.

Here is the form code (I'm using ColdFusion, but for this it shouldn't matter):

```
<form name="requestForm" id="requestForm" method="post" action="">          

  <!-- Serial Numbers -->
  <label for="txtSerialNumbers">Serial Numbers
  <textarea name="txtSerialNumbers" id="txtSerialNumbers"></textarea>          

  <!-- Action Buttons -->
  <button type="submit" name="addTokens" id="addTokens" >Add Tokens</button>

</form>
```

And here is the jQuery Validation code that works for the one line:

```
   <script>

        $(document).ready( function () {

            $.validator.addMethod("checkSerials", function(value, element) {  
                    if (/^[0-9A-Z]{4}(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})$/.test(value)) {       
                            return true; // pass when validation is correct
                    } else {
                            return false; // fail when validation fails
                    };
                }, "Please enter a valid Serial Number."

            );              

            $('#requestForm').validate( {       

                    rules: {
                            txtSerialNumbers: {
                                    checkSerials: true
                            }           
                    }                                               
            });

        });

    </script>
```

I'm assuming I will need to loop as I don't think Regex itself can check each line of the textarea separately without looping, or can it?  I'm still learning Javascript so I'm not sure where I should put the loop or how to break out of the loop when it reaches a bad Serial Number (no sense in parsing the whole textarea if a failure occurs on line 1).

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Could you tidy up your code to just give the bit that's relevant to the question please?

Comment: your regex could be shortened if desired to something like `([0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4}){4}`

Comment: Code shortened.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your validator method, you can Split the value up using `split()` and then return false if any of the rows don't match.  Something like this:

```
             $.validator.addMethod("checkSerials", function(value, element) {  
                var pattern  = /^[0-9A-Z]{4}(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})$/;
                var allLines = value.split('\n');
                foreach (var i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++)
                {
                   if (!pattern.test(allLines[i])
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
                }
                return true; // pass when validation is correct
            }, "Please enter a valid Serial Number."

        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to everyone' for their help.  Specifically, thanks Stephen for the 99% solution.  Just had to make a few tweaks and it's working the way I wanted:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("checkSerials", function(value, element) { 

        var pattern  = /^[0-9A-Z]{4}(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})$/;             
        var allLines = $('#txtSerialNumbers').val().split('\n');                                    

            for (var i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++)
            {
                if (!pattern.test(allLines[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                 }
            }

            return true; // pass when validation is correct                     

       }, "Please enter a valid Serial Number." 

   );
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can split up new lines by using `var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n')`. This creates an array (kind of like a list) with all the lines as 'terms'. You can then do a for loop to go through all these terms:

```
$.each(terms, function(index, value) {
    // Do regex on value variable here for just the current line
});
```

Comment: `s/a variable (kind of like a list) with all the lines as 'terms'/an Array with each line as an array element/`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write array, will update now. But was trying to simplify my answer in case the asker wasn't familiar with arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very good with arrays yet but I'll give it a go.

Comment: OK, if you find my answer useful would you consider upvoting it and accepting it please.